# Pulling up unique values using sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The data I am looking at is as below

```
ID  Name    Date
1   ABC 7/31/2013
1   AB  7/31/2012
1   ABCD    8/1/2011
1   AB  8/1/2010
1   ABD 8/1/2009
2   DEF 7/31/2013
2   DE  7/31/2012
2   DEF 8/1/2011
2   D   8/1/2010
2   DE  8/1/2009
```

I am trying to write an sql which will pull up unique items in the "Name" column only when there is a change. For example, the output I get should be the one below

```
ID  Name    Date
1   ABC 7/31/2013
1   ABCD    8/1/2011
1   AB  8/1/2010
2   DEF 7/31/2013
2   D   8/1/2011
2   DE  8/1/2009
```

Comment: you need to get record with previous date ?

Comment: And what have you tried yet?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean? How do you determine the unique values? Do you need to group the similar names, then pull out the one with the latest date?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Name, Date from table t
where not exists 
(select 1 from table where ID = t.ID and name = t.name and t.Date > Date)
```

It seems you are missing

```
1   ABD 8/1/2009
```

from your expected result